# RegEx: Add Quantifier to Capturing Group for all results

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following strings that are valid...

```
 "   1"
 "  12"
 " 123"
 "1234"
 " 123"
 " 12A"
 ""
```

The following string are NOT valid...

```
"   1234"
" 1234"
"0 12"
"0012"
```

Currently I use the following regex match to check if the string is valid...

```
"(|[0-9A-Z\-]{4}| {1}[0-9A-Z\-]{3}| {2}[0-9A-Z\-]{2}| {3}[0-9A-Z\-]{1})"
```

Note: To be clear, the above regex will NOT meet my requirements, that's why I'm asking this question.

I was hoping there was a simpler match I could use, something like the following...

```
"(| {0,3}[0-9A-Z\-]{1,4})"
```

The only problem I have is that the above will also match this like `"   1234"` which is not acceptable.  Is there a way for me to limit the capture group I have to only 4 characters?

Comment: Could not figure out the rules. Could you clarify ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown 1) It has to have 4 characters (A-Z0-9) with leading spaces. 2) Can not accept leading zeros.

Comment: It would be great to get feedback as to why this question was voted down (opposed to a hit and run).  I think the question is very clear and well-formed.  I would be more than happy to edit it to suit anyone's needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the match can not start with a zero, you could add a negative lookahead as Wiktor previously commented:

```
"(?="|.{4}")(?! *0)[0-9A-Z -]*"
```

**Explanation**

- `"` Match literally
- `(?="|.{4}")` If what is directly on the right is either " or 4 chars followed by "
- `(?! *0)` If what is direcly on the right is not 0+ spaces followed by a zero
- `[0-9A-Z -]*` Match 0+ times what is listed in the character class
- `"` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RlhVJG/1)

If the spaces can only occur at the beginning you could use:

```
"(?="|.{4}")(?! *0) *[0-9A-Z-]+"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j6VDI2/2)

Comment: A few things...  1) This does not account for the quotes around the string, and it needs to.  2) The anchors would not help me because this is going to be in the middle of a string.  - When I take off the anchors It's not matching something like `" 123"` and I need it to.

Comment: This looks like a winner, thanks!  I have never used `lookahead` before but it looks like that's the key.  Also to see this answer in action.. https://regex101.com/r/j6VDI2/1

Answer (score 2):

This would pass all your test cases:

```
"(|[1-9\s][0-9A-Z\s]{2}[0-9A-Z])"
```

Though I suspect there are cases you might not have mentioned.

Explanation: match either 0 or 4 characters between double quotes. First character may be a space or digit but not a zero. Next two characters are any digit or capital letter or space. Fourth character is a digit or capital but not a space.

Comment: It does indeed!  Nice and simple as well.  Your suspicions are unfounded.  ;)  There is nothing more to the requirements other than.. 1) It has to have 4 characters (A-Z0-9) with leading spaces.  2) Can not accept leading zeros.

Comment: I wish there was a way to accept two answers.  The fourth bird beat you to it but both are valid!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make it a bit more efficient:

`"(?:[A-Z\d-]{4}|[ ](?:[A-Z\d-]{3}|[ ](?:[A-Z\d-]|[ ])[A-Z\d-]))"`

https://regex101.com/r/1fr9tb/1

```
 "
 (?:
      [A-Z\d-]{4} 
   |  [ ]
      (?:
           [A-Z\d-]{3} 
        |  [ ]
           (?: [A-Z\d-] | [ ] )
           [A-Z\d-]
      )
 )
 "
```

Benchmarks

```
Regex1:   "(?:[A-Z\d-]{4}|[ ](?:[A-Z\d-]{3}|[ ](?:[A-Z\d-]|[ ])[A-Z\d-]))"
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   7
Elapsed Time:    0.66 s,   663.84 ms,   663843 µs
Matches per sec:   527,233


Regex2:   "(|[0-9A-Z\-]{4}|[ ]{1}[0-9A-Z\-]{3}|[ ]{2}[0-9A-Z\-]{2}|[ ]{3}[0-9A-Z\-]{1})"
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   7
Elapsed Time:    0.94 s,   938.44 ms,   938438 µs
Matches per sec:   372,960


Regex3:   "(?="|.{4}")(?![ ]*0)[0-9A-Z -]*"
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   6
Elapsed Time:    0.73 s,   728.48 ms,   728484 µs
Matches per sec:   411,814

Regex4:   "(|[1-9\s][0-9A-Z\s]{2}[0-9A-Z])"
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   6
Elapsed Time:    0.85 s,   851.48 ms,   851481 µs
Matches per sec:   352,327
```

Comment: This does not meet the requirements (as seen in your own example on regex101).

Comment: @ArvoBowen - `This does not meet the requirements (as seen in your own example on regex101)`  I believed I used your requirements. https://regex101.com/r/PLfKOc/1 Before you turn into a spec writer I suggest you learn how.

Comment: I was simply trying to inform you that I had a list of acceptable string and a list of unacceptable string in my original question.  You used those same strings and your regex matches both strings on the acceptable list and non-acceptable list.  If my regex was working I would not have posted a question here.  No reason to get hot about feedback.

Comment: @ArvoBowen - Some people feel the need to justify the answer they picked, by commenting the other answers some flaw in their answer. I don't care one way or the other, except when the comment is in error. And, like a lot of posters, you've altered you question after the fact to justify any actions or comments you've made. Again, it doesn't bother me a bit. Its a small world here in regex land and, I'm here all the time bro..